# ldapTemplate.search returns empty list on searchControles

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to get details of a user. When providing the SearchControls, it returns an empty list.

```
@Override
public User getUserDetails(String userName) {
    SearchControls ctls= new SearchControls();
    String [] attrs = {"mail"};
    ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrs);

    log.info("executing {getUserDetails}");
    List<User> list = ldapTemplate.search("","(&(objectClass=person)(mail=josh.nail@gmail.com))",ctls, new UserAttributesMapper());
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If we call

`ldapTemplate.search("","(&(objectClass=person)(mail=josh.nail@gmail.com))", new UserAttributesMapper());`

with out the searchcontroles, it fetches the user details. Is there any specific criteria to be followed while setting the ReturningAttributes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the `SearchControls`, the `LdapTemplate.search()` will use its `defaultSearchScope`, which by default is `SearchControl#SUBTREE_SCOPE`.

If you pass your own `SearchControls` objects, `LdapTemplate.search()` will use the `searchScope` that is defined whithin your `SearchControls`.

`SearchControls ctls= new SearchControls();` however sets the `searchScope` to `SearchControls#ONELEVEL_SCOPE`, so your search will only find entries that are direct children of the search base.

To make a long story short, you usually want to create a `SearchControls` object like this:

```
SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String [] attrs = {"mail"};
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrs);
```